# How to Copy Data From Local Postgres DB to Heroku PostgresDB

Tags: django, postgresql, data-migration

I have a local (dev) database that I just populated with data by importing a .csv file. I have an empty (prod) remote database on Heroku that I would like to populate with the same data.  Both databases are postgres and are completely identical in terms of their schema.  I would think this would be an easy operation, but I have not found an answer on how to do this.

One thing I tried was:

```
heroku db:push
```

But then I got the error:

```
Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- sqlite3
You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
```

I updated taps only to get the same error. Can someone either tell me how to copy the data from my local db to my remote db or how to push the .csv file to my remote server and then I can upload it on the psql line from there?

Comment: You seem to have configured for a local SQLite db, while you actually use Postgres locally as well (which is good).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been long time I haven't use django.
You can try this:
Put your csv file in app/sql directory.
If for example your csv file is for a model named *mymodel*,
you create mymodel.sql inside that directory and inside that sql file is
your sql statement to input data from csv.

And then when you invoke

```
heroku python manage.py syncdb
```

those *.sql files should be executed by django.

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

Comment: I was able to get it to work using Django Fixtures from the docs link you provided. Thanks!